# transition causing text and button to hide behind an image

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, pseudo-element

I have a login page that I have been playing around with, and there seems to be a problem with the text and buttons disappearing behind an image when a transition is complete. To get a sense of the problem check out https://codepen.io/suez/pen/RpNXOR, this is where I got the code from originally and shows the problem. Once you click the signup button and the transition occurs, the buttons and text on the other side seem to disappear behind the image.

CODE FROM codepen

HTML

```
<p class="tip">Click on button in image container</p>
<div class="cont">
  <div class="form sign-in">
    <h2>Welcome back,</h2>
    <label>
      <span>Email</span>
      <input type="email" />
    </label>
    <label>
      <span>Password</span>
      <input type="password" />
    </label>
    <p class="forgot-pass">Forgot password?</p>
    <button type="button" class="submit">Sign In</button>
    <button type="button" class="fb-btn">Connect with <span>facebook</span></button>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-cont">
    <div class="img">
      <div class="img__text m--up">
        <h2>New here?</h2>
        <p>Sign up and discover great amount of new opportunities!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="img__text m--in">
        <h2>One of us?</h2>
        <p>If you already has an account, just sign in. We've missed you!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="img__btn">
        <span class="m--up">Sign Up</span>
        <span class="m--in">Sign In</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form sign-up">
      <h2>Time to feel like home,</h2>
      <label>
        <span>Name</span>
        <input type="text" />
      </label>
      <label>
        <span>Email</span>
        <input type="email" />
      </label>
      <label>
        <span>Password</span>
        <input type="password" />
      </label>
      <button type="button" class="submit">Sign Up</button>
      <button type="button" class="fb-btn">Join with <span>facebook</span></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS(scss)

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  background: #ededed;
}

input, button {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

$contW: 900px;
$imgW: 260px;
$formW: $contW - $imgW;
$switchAT: 1.2s;

$inputW: 260px;
$btnH: 36px;

$diffRatio: ($contW - $imgW) / $contW;

@mixin signUpActive {
  .cont.s--signup & {
    @content;
  }
}

.tip {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 40px auto 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.cont {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: $contW;
  height: 550px;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  background: #fff;
}

.form {
  position: relative;
  width: $formW;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform $switchAT ease-in-out;
  padding: 50px 30px 0;
}

.sub-cont {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: $formW;
  top: 0;
  width: $contW;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: $imgW;
  background: #fff;
  transition: transform $switchAT ease-in-out;

  @include signUpActive {
    transform: translate3d($formW * -1,0,0);
  }
}

button {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: $inputW;
  height: $btnH;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.img {
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: $imgW;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 360px;

  &:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: $contW;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/142996/sections-3.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    transition: transform $switchAT ease-in-out;
  }

  &:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  }

  @include signUpActive {
    &:before {
      transform: translate3d($formW,0,0);
    }
  }

  &__text {
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    transition: transform $switchAT ease-in-out;

    h2 {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      font-weight: normal;
    }

    p {
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 1.5;
    }

    &.m--up {

      @include signUpActive {
        transform: translateX($imgW*2);
      }
    }

    &.m--in {
      transform: translateX($imgW * -2);

      @include signUpActive {
        transform: translateX(0);
      }
    }
  }

  &__btn {
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: $btnH;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: transparent;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    
    &:after {
      content: '';
      z-index: 2;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border: 2px solid #fff;
      border-radius: 30px;
    }

    span {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      transition: transform $switchAT;
      
      &.m--in {
        transform: translateY($btnH*-2);
        
        @include signUpActive {
          transform: translateY(0);
        }
      }
      
      &.m--up {
        @include signUpActive {
          transform: translateY($btnH*2);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

h2 {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-align: center;
}

label {
  display: block;
  width: $inputW;
  margin: 25px auto 0;
  text-align: center;

  span {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #cfcfcf;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
}

input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  text-align: center;
}

.forgot-pass {
  margin-top: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #cfcfcf;
}

.submit {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #d4af7a;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.fb-btn {
  border: 2px solid #d3dae9;
  color: darken(#d3dae9, 20%);

  span {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: darken(#768cb6, 20%);
  }
}

.sign-in {
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;

  @include signUpActive {
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transition-duration: $switchAT;
    transform: translate3d($formW,0,0);
  }
}

.sign-up {
  transform: translate3d($contW * -1,0,0);

  @include signUpActive {
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  }
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
document.querySelector('.img__btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('.cont').classList.toggle('s--signup');
});
```

I have also included my updated version: https://jsfiddle.net/onsamesid3/5stc30n8/8/, but the problem is not shown here as there is no image, and when there is no image the problem seems to disappear. I'm curious as to why the text and buttons disappear behind the image once the transition is complete and if there is a way to sort it.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Working find for me: https://jsfiddle.net/moshfeu/v53syk2f/1/

Comment: it must be my browser then as once you press the sign-up button and the transition is complete the sign-in button that is supposed to appear on the other side, vanishes behind the image.

Comment: What is your browser?

Comment: safari 11.1, would see why it would be the browser but not sure why it would work fine for you and not me and I can't seem to see a solution.

Comment: I tested on Chrome. Can you try?

Comment: I have but there I no difference.